# Descargar archivo por FTP en PHP

Tags: php, ftp

Tenía este código que me estaba funcionando perfecto para descargar archivos por FTP desde PHP, pero desde un tiempo está descargando los archivos dañados, quisiera  identificar lo que estoy haciendo mal.

```
$nombre_archivo = $_GET['archivo'];
$destino = $_GET['ruta'];

$ini = parse_ini_file('C:\credenciales.ini', true);

$local_file = 'C:/' . $nombre_archivo;
$server_file = $destino . '/' . $nombre_archivo;
$ftp_server = $ini['FTP']['host'];
$ftp_usuario = $ini['FTP']['user'];
$ftp_pass = $ini['FTP']['pass'];

$con_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$lr = ftp_login($con_id, $ftp_usuario, $ftp_pass);

if ((!$con_id) || (!$lr)) {
    echo 'ERROR DE CONEXION AL SERVIDOR ';
} else {
    if (ftp_get($con_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
        echo 'ARCHIVO DESCARGADO CORRECTAMENTE ';
    } else {
        echo 'ERROR EN LA DESCARGA DEL ARCHIVO ';
    }
    ftp_close($con_id);
}

header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $nombre_archivo);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($local_file));
readfile($local_file);
```

Los archivos están subiendo bien, pero al momento de descargarlos y abrirlos aparecen dañados.

Comment: Quita todos esos `echo`, eso corrompe el archivo.

Comment: Efectivamente funcionó quitando todos los echo, ahora mi duda es porqué antes funcionaba bien? Y ahora debo romperme la cabeza para ubicar esos validadores, traté de cambiar los echo por true y false pero de esa manera no descarga el archivo.

Comment: ¿Cómo cambiar los `echo` por `TRUE` y `FALSE`?, no entiendo muy bien lo que quieres decir.  Realmente lo que debes hacer es meter el código que descarga el archivo en el bloque donde sería válida la descarga y en los bloques donde no es válida imprimir un mensaje de error. Con eso lo tienes resuelto. En caso de éxito, la confirmación sería la descarga misma del archivo, así que esto no tiene sentido: `echo 'ARCHIVO DESCARGADO CORRECTAMENTE ';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El archivo se corrompe porque tienes un `echo` que sale por pantalla dentro del flujo del programa.

Además no lo tienes organizado de una forma lógica. Lo correcto sería poner el código de descarga solamente en la parte donde se cumplen las condiciones que hace que el archivo esté disponible para descargar y sea del tipo que esperas.

```
<?php 
    $nombre_archivo = $_GET['archivo'];
    $destino = $_GET['ruta'];

    $ini = parse_ini_file('C:\credenciales.ini', true);

    $local_file = 'C:/' . $nombre_archivo;
    $server_file = $destino . '/' . $nombre_archivo;
    $ftp_server = $ini['FTP']['host'];
    $ftp_usuario = $ini['FTP']['user'];
    $ftp_pass = $ini['FTP']['pass'];

    $con_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
    $lr = ftp_login($con_id, $ftp_usuario, $ftp_pass);

    if ((!$con_id) || (!$lr)) {
        echo 'ERROR DE CONEXION AL SERVIDOR ';
    } else {
        if (ftp_get($con_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
            header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $nombre_archivo);
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($local_file));
            readfile($local_file);
        } else {
            echo 'ERROR EN LA DESCARGA DEL ARCHIVO ';
        }
        ftp_close($con_id);
    }
?>
```